# Importing Solana Mnemonics with Python

Tags: python, solana

I need to use HD wallets with pysolana.

Hello everyone,
I'm working on solana with Python. I can generate random Solana wallets with the code I wrote below.

```py
mnemo = Mnemonic("english")
my_words = mnemo.generate(128)
    
seed_bytes = Bip39SeedGenerator(my_words).Generate("")
bip44_mst_ctx = Bip44.FromSeed(seed_bytes, Bip44Coins.SOLANA)
bip44_acc_ctx = bip44_mst_ctx.Purpose().Coin().Account(0)
bip44_chg_ctx = bip44_acc_ctx.Change(Bip44Changes.CHAIN_EXT)
ADDR = bip44_chg_ctx.PublicKey().ToAddress()
```

But here's the problem, these wallets are HD Wallets. If I want to use these wallets, I need to import these seeds into the `solders` library. But the `solders` library does not support HD wallets.

The only useful Python Solana library is also coded to work with the `solders` library.

Here is the urls:
https://michaelhly.com/solana-py/rpc/api/#solana.rpc.api.Client.send_transaction
Solders keypairs: https://kevinheavey.github.io/solders/tutorials/keypairs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HD wallet support has been added.
https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/pull/75

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is all correct, you just need to use the secret key bytes from `bip44_chg_ctx` to create a `Keypair`, ie:

```
keypair = Keypair.from_seed(bip44_chg_ctx.PrivateKey().Raw().ToBytes())
```

Note that the documentation for `Raw()` on `Bip44PrivateKey` seems to be incorrect: https://github.com/ebellocchia/bip_utils/blob/fc9e7723a7cf44c964976694912818ccd027936a/bip_utils/bip/bip44_base/bip44_keys.py#L189C28-L189C28